# Remove password from Galaxy Tab4

Tags: encryption, samsung-galaxy-tab, password

My wife set password to her tablet and asks me to remove it. I opened `settings -> security -> device encryption` entering password but option `none` (i.e. no password) is disabled (with message `turned off by administrator, policy...`). As I understand if I am able to set password to `none` then password should disappears. But I cannot do it, so I suspecting that she is encrypted device somehow.

Is there way to ensure that device encrypted or not? If it is encrypted there is only one way, as I know, hard reset it to remove encryption. But if it is not encrypted, how to remove password?

Comment: In *Settings→Security→Device Administrators*, check whether some app is listed there. The error message suggests such. If there's e.g. an MS Exchange account configured, things like that are enforced (and your company's IT admin could factory-reset your device if he feels like =:-0).

Comment: @Izzy it is her private device, not related to any company. anyway, it was solved by reset to factory defaults.

Comment: MS Exchange was only one example – there might be other things doing the same. And sure: if you drop atomics on a fly, it will die :) Factory-reset is the "last resort" solution for many things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, after couple of days spent on lurking for the solution was decided to backup photos and other sensitive information and reset device to factory defaults.

Answer (score 2):

1.From any home screen, tap Apps.

2.Tap Settings

3.Tap the Device tab.

4.Under 'PERSONALIZATION,' tap Lock screen.

5.Tap Screen lock.

6.Confirm your PIN / password, then tap Continue.

7.Tap None.

Comment: Option is disabled and cannot be selected.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to the settings.
2. Tap the device icon on the top.
3. Select lock screen in personalization.
4. Select screen lock. Confirm password and make in none or whatever  else.